# Função .unload() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu faço duas requisições ajax para um arquivo externo do qual adicionam e removem produtos, porém isso não é muito relevante nessa questão. Eu queria que toda vez que a página fosse atualizada, a função `removeCartaotoCart` fosse acionada para que segundo o id do produto selecionado, o mesmo fosse retirado antes da página ser recarregada.

**Código das requisições Ajax:**

```
var productSelected = "";

            function addCartao(product){
                if( productSelected != "" ){
                    removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);
                  }
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product).show();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "adiciona.php",
                  data: {
                    product: product
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {

                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product);
                    productSelected = product;                   
                    $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend'+product+'"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();
                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                  }
              });
            }

            function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
                console.log('Entrou');
                console.log(itemId);
                productSelected = ""; 
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
                $j.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"remove.php",
                    data:{
                        itemId: itemId
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){

                    },
                    success: function(retorno){
                        var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);  
                        $j('.item-custom #trAppend'+itemId+'').remove();
                        getSubTotal();
                        getGrandTotal();

                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                  }
                });
            }

        $j(window).unload(function(){
            console.log('Recarregando ...');
            console.log(productSelected);
            removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);
        });
```

**Observação: Eu tentei fazer a função `.unload()`, mas me retorna erros (`[object Object]`) e o produto não é removido.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que não tem como fazer essa requisição pela função `.unload()`, pois além do erro, ele "quebraria" essa requisição no meio. No caso, ela deve ser feita no carregamento da página, por meio do seguinte código:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Carregando ...');
    console.log(productSelected);
    removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);
});
```